# Serde deserialization of partial structs with actix_web

Tags: json, rust, serde, actix-web

I have an API endpoint that utilizes `actix_web` to deserialize an incoming JSON payload (`actix_web` ultimately uses `serde` for JSON deserialization).

As an example, I have something that looks like this:

```rust
pub struct IncomingPayload {
    pub field1: i32,
    pub field2: String
}

pub async fn update_platforms(
    pool: web::Data<Pool>,
    req: web::Json<Vec<IncomingPayload>>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, error::Error> { 
    println!(req.field1); // will be an i32
    println!(req.field2); // will be a String
}
```

Currently, this endpoint will only successfully return if `serde` is able to deserialize all fields of the struct. I.e. A request must contain `field1` and `field2` keys.

E.g. this would be successful:

```sh
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"field1": 1,"field2":"something"}' \
  http://localhost:8080
```

But this would not (because `field2` is missing from the payload):

```sh
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"field1": 1}' \
  http://localhost:8080
```

So my question is, can this be done? Can one send a JSON payload with a subset of key-value fields to an `actix_web` endpoint that expects all the fields to be present?

Or rather, is there a generic way to deserialize partial structs like this with `actix_web` or `serde`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Option<T>` as the type for a field to have it be optional. If a field is missing during deserialization, the field is set to `None`, otherwise it is set to `Some(value)`.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct IncomingPayload {
    pub field1: Option<i32>,
    pub field2: Option<String>,
}
```

For types that implement `Default`, you can also use the `#[serde(default)]` to set the field to the default value if the field is missing.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct IncomingPayload {
    #[serde(default)] // default = 0
    pub field1: i32,
    #[serde(default)] // default = empty string
    pub field2: String,
}
```